# mysqli equivalent to mysql_query("BEGIN")

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm in the process of upgrading our code base from PHP5.4 to PHP7.  in our tests we wrap the entire test in a transaction with the command

mysql_query("BEGIN");

then do a bunch of stuff

mysql_query("ROLLBACK");

then everything between those two commands was treated as a transaction and could be rolled back at the end of the test. i have not been able to achieve this functionality in PHP7 with mysqli.  i tried using the mysqli_autocommit function but then this did not allow different queries within the test to have access to created data earlier in the test. it was as if each insert was in its own transaction.

UPDATE:

the issue is that every time i create a new adapter to a table, it seems i am creating a new connection to the db.  with PHP5 and the command above 'mysql_query("BEGIN")'  EVERY connection was contained in that transaction and all statements could be rolled back.  i have not found a way to do this with php7. if i use the

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
```

then ONLY that single connection is part of the transaction. in order to achieve my desired functionality, i have to implicitly force EVERY adapter to use the existing connection rather then creating their own. i imagine there is probably a way that PHP7 does this automatically for you? since now the only way i could figure out how to do it is to set a GLOBAL and if it exists to use the connection rather than create a new one. so my question still stands, is there a way to force all connections that get opened to be contained in a transaction that can be rolled back, and a further question here is what is best practice about re-using connections as i'm sure setting a global is the wrong way to do it.

I am using MySQL 5.5.52. PHP 7.0.10

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

Comment: @RocketHazmat i tried that but all inserts and updates are registering as commited and are fully accessable after the test has completed.

Comment: What is the database engine?

Comment: What version of `mysql RDBMS`, and what  version of `PHP mysqli` are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL  5.5.52.  PHP 7.0.10

Comment: Be sure not to mix calls to `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`; use only the latter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i imagine there is probably a way that PHP7 does this automatically for you?

No.

> the only way i could figure out how to do it is to set a GLOBAL

Not quite.

You could use OOP instead and provide a single SQL adapter instance for all the classes that may need it. However, if your code is procedural, you may keep with either global variable or a singleton helper class.

Comment: so is it considered bad practice to open a new connection for each db query then for a particular session?

Comment: yes, exactly. I'd even say it's just unacceptable practice - both for performance and usability reasons

Answer (score 0):

[begin_transaction](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) is what you're looking for. It is used like so:

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
```